# Is it possible to override Android's sound driver OMTP implementation to work in CTIA standard?

Tags: android, audio, driver

I have Android device compatible with OMTP headphones, the only difference with CTIA is that 3rd and 4th pin in minijack are in reverse order(OMTP is Nokia's property while CTIA is Apple's idea).

[image]

Is it possible to gain software access to the minijack's pins and override driver's behaviour or modify driver itself? It might be just pair of `static final` fields to swap.

**INFO:** I know that this question is hardware related, but I am looking for software side solution (hardware side is buying an adapter or soldering a new minijack). I looked thoroughly and nobody tried it yet or stated similar question.